# Insert Background images Using HTML and CSS, not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a background image for my milkshake survey.I have an image that is integrated in the code.The image only seems to show up for a split second only when i am spamming "refresh" on the google chrome browser and then it disappears.

I have looked and tried everywhere on stack overflow and YouTube tutorials but cant seem to find the solution.
But for some reason it works on Codepen.io(my following link):
https://codepen.io/abhirajsb/pen/WNwRjqO

I have already checked the directory for the image and seem to be correct.
Here is the screenshot of the image directory:
from VSCODE:
[image: Image directory on VSCODE]

from DESKSTOP:
[image]
I am using the VSCODE editor with "live server" extension.

```css
@font-face {
  src: url(fonts/GreatVibes.ttf);
  font-family: GreatVibes;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://cimg1.ibsrv.net/cimg/www.fitday.com/693x350_85-1/793/milk-105793.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

#MS {
  text-align: center;
  color: #d54d7b;
  font-family: "GreatVibes", cursive;
  font-size: 165px;
  line-height: 160px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
}

#description {
  text-align: center;
  color: #7a7c7f;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
  line-height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="survey.css" />

<head>
  <title>Milkshake Survey 2020</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="MS">Milkshake Survey</h1>
  <p id="description">
    Thank you for taking the time for making our Milkshakes tastier
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works in a snippet too

Comment: If you inspect the body after it loads, is the image property still there? Sounds like maybe there is some javascript removing the image on load.

Comment: I don't see any issue for background image in the above code snippet. I checked in both safari & chrome. It works fine. Use a different the image server and try.